# Vue router mode 'history' not working in development server

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue 3 and Vue Router. My app is working with `createWebHashHistory`, but when I change to `mode: 'history'` the pages don't load.

```
const router = createRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

I know that in production I have to configure the server to use `mode: 'history'`, but I'm serving the app in a development server using `npm run serve`.

Answer (score 2):

If this problem occurs, it may be a configuration problem. Check if the publicPath in `vue.config.js` or `config/index.js` is `/` instead of `./`

Comment: That worked in my case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mode: 'history': does not directly access the project in the production environment, need nginx forwarding,You can use CreateWebhashhistory

Answer (score 0):

This is a Breaking Changes.

The mode: 'history' option has been replaced with a more flexible one named history. Depending on which mode you were using, you will have to replace it with the appropriate function:

- "history": `createWebHistory()`
- "hash": `createWebHashHistory()`
- "abstract": `createMemoryHistory()`

Therefore, you need to update your code to the new way:

```js
createRouter({
  // mode: 'history',
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [],
})
```

The `createRouter` receives an options of type `RouterOptions`, it has no `mode` attribute.

So, `mode: 'history'` is not work anymore.

You can see more [here(new history option to replace mode)](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#new-history-option-to-replace-mode)

Comment: `createWebHistory()` isn't working either, only `createWebHashHistory()`

Answer (score 0):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback
It works for me, in vue.config.js

devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true,
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).